# How to protect slash in asp.net mvc and avoid "Failed to map the path" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got this razor html in a area in my ASP.NET MVC project:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AMOAResponsible, Model.AMOAResponsible ?? string.Empty)
</td>
```

Everything is ok when the value of AMOAResponsible is something like "Lorem Ipsum".
But sometimes the value "AMOAResponsible" contains a slash (e. g. "LOREM/IPSUM") and then I get the following error:

> Failed to map the path
>   '/Areas/Dashboard/Views/Psr/DisplayTemplates/LOREM/IPSUM.aspx'.

I have no idea how to fix this. Can I protect the `"/"` ?

Comment: You mean `Model.AMOAResponsible` contains the view name to render (you're calling the `DisplayFor(modelExpression, viewName)` overload). How is the "LOREM/IPSUM" view actually named in your project?

Comment: @CodeCaster The view is in a dedicated area in the website, using `RegisterArea` method (I didn't code it, I just need to update the code in a view in this area). I need to display the value of the property *AMOResponsible* in the model. Everything is ok with values like "Lorem Ipsum" but if there is a slash in the value I've got the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: What are you attempting to do by including `Model.AMOAResponsible ?? string.Empty` (which means your calling the name of a display template) Just remove it

Comment: I don't think you understand. With your call, you are telling MVC to render the view named like the value of `Model.AMOAResponsible`. So if that variable contains "LOREM/IPSUM", it will try to find a view named "IPSUM" in the folder "LOREM". Why is that there, and how did you name your views?

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right... I didn't know what it means so I left it like that but this cause the error. I removed it and it works thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String%29) of `@HtmlDisplayFor()` where the second parameter is `templateName` and specifies the name of the `DisplayTemplate` to use to render the property

If the value of `AMOAResponsible` is (say) "Lorem", the method will search the `/Views/yourControllerName/DisplayTemplates` folder and search for a file named `Lorem.cshtml` or `Lorem.aspx`, which wont exist, so it then searches in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` which also wont exist, so it uses the default `DisplayTemplate` (no exception is thrown - but just wasted some processing time)

If however the value is Lorem/Ipsum it will start searching in `/Views/yourControllerName/Lorem/DisplayTemplates` but because the folder does not exist an exception is thrown.

I assume you are under the belief that `Model.AMOAResponsible ?? string.Empty` would render an 'empty string' if the value of Model.AMOAResponsible is `null`, but the helper does that anyway (i.e. generates no output) so just remove it. The helper should be just

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AMOAResponsible)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Any words of wisdom if you're getting this problem when using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Object%29) of `DisplayFor`?

Comment: @PhilPursglove, You linked to the page listing all the overloads :) - I don't know which one your referring to.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Apologies, it was meant to link to the internal link on the page for the second overload e.g. `DisplayFor(expression, object)`

Comment: @PhilPursglove, So what problems are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Same as the OP, when the value returned by `expression` contains a / character, I see the 'Failed to map the path ...' exception

Comment: @PhilPursglove. You could only be getting that error if you passing a string which means you not using the `DisplayFor(expression, object)` overload (which is for adding additionalViewData). Your going to need to ask a new question showing the code your using and the details of the error